# Class that convert datatabase to arrays

Tags: android

I wan't to make a class that I will use to convert database tables to arrays. For that I need access to the Context. What should I implement or extend to access it properly?

Is this a good idead to just extend the class that consists database helper?

Comment: How many columns does this database have? An array is not the correct data structure if you have more then 2 columns.

Comment: Why not? It could be multidimensional array, couldn't be? But that's not really the point. I need this class for some operations on a database. I want it to gather information to the arrays, for other classes so they don't have to acess database anymore, which would be innefficient

Comment: Is your issue mainly related to getting access to Context or how to implement that class??

Comment: Possibly a litle bit of both. I got the DatabaseHelper class which consist a database. I wan't to make sure I acess the context properly so there won't be exceptions later

Comment: there won't be any exceptions with the way i told you as the Application context is alive till the application is running.

Comment: thanks. I'm gonna give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that extends Application and an Application class object has a context

```
 public class Main extends Application{
    public Context context;
    public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    context= this;  }
    }
```

Access the context  statically anywhere using Main.context 
Make sure you declare application class in Manifest file
It can be done as :

```
<application android:name=".Main" 
       android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
       android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Edited a question a little bit, could you take a look plz?

Answer (score 1):

Context is provided by any of the major components of the Android system. This includes: Activities, Services, Broadcast Receivers, and Content Providers. 
While not all of the contexts are implemented the same, I am pretty sure they all have the ability to access the DB.

Comment: Edited a question a little bit, could you take a look plz?

Comment: So what you can do is have a class that works as your DB Helper, and pass the context as an argument to the constructor from the activity, service, or whatever is calling it. That will give your DBHelper class access to Context.

Comment: Some code for the constructor of my DB Adapter
 public RufusDBAdaptor(Context _context)
 {
  context = _context;
  dbHelper = new DBHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  dbLocalHelper = new DBHelper(context, LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME, null, LOCAL_DATABASE_VERSION);
 }